# Identify a WWII-time building in Belgium

Tags: belgium, identify-this, brussels, war-zones

Can someone help me identify a building in the background of this old photo (or at least a geographic location of this place, if this building does not exist anymore):

[image]

All I know, is that this picutre was taken in Belgium (most likely in Brussels), somewhere around  1944.

Comment: This question should belong to history se

Comment: Try asking these guys https://www.afterthebattle.com/store/index.php?controller=search&search_query=belgium&orderby=position&orderway=desc&n=20 They have lots of urban photos on a then/now frame

Comment: This is a prototypical [tag:identify-this] question and IMHO belongs on Travel. Voting to leave open.

Comment: Are any of the signs legible on the original photograph?  How about the soldier's uniform?  Do you know what army or unit he belonged to?  How certain are you of the date on which the photograph was taken, or that it was in fact taken in Belgium?

Comment: The only help I can offer is that it's a broad road - probably a major junction, but probably not an open plaza, as he's standing on flagstones (pavement?) and the area behind him is cobbled (road). There are also tramlines, so if you can find a contemporary map of where the trams ran, it might help narrow down possible locations.

Comment: But @phoog is right - *if* you can make out the wording on the signs, or get a better scan, there'd be more chance of identifying it.

Comment: @Andrew I also found that looking on Google maps street view reveals almost no buildings of that height and vintage in Brussels.  So it might be in a part of the city I couldn't find, or it might be in a part of the city that has been rebuilt since the war.

Comment: @phoog oh, good, I wasn't the only one who did that :-). I found a couple of similarly styled large buildings - both now hotels - but neither large enough. I suspect this one, if it still exists, may also be a hotel now.

Comment: @phoog As per my knowledge, my wife's grandfather was a part of General Maczek's troops (Polish Forces). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Maczek#To_Germany), _end of July 1944 the Polish 1st Armoured Division was transferred to Normandy_. And as per given answer below, it is certainly Brussels, and the begin / middle of September, 1944.

Comment: @Andrew Making better scan won't help here, because the original photograph is already very old and in quite poor quality (seems, that war time photography wasn't too good).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's Hôtel Le Dôme, Place Rogier, Brussels, Belgium.

[image]

You can see this building on [Google Street view](https://goo.gl/maps/frRYQ9Ack5n) - pretty much the same today as it was in the photo.

Comment: Well done - very impressed!

Comment: +1, props and admiration for your research and timely answer. And thanks for the street view link!

Comment: Travel.SE is extremely impressive - not a single 'identify-this' request went unanswered!

Comment: Man, if only the camera had been slightly higher, the words "Hotel Le Dome" would have appeared in the original photo and everything would have been so much easier.

Comment: It looks like the Drug Opera building but I don't see the sign so I guess not.

Comment: After a quick image search, definitely not the same building. Notably, the lack of a protruding dome. https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/big-yellow-drug-opera-building-city-center-big-yellow-drug-opera-building-city-center-brussels-metropolitan-city-185756315.jpg This is in tourist central near the Grand Place.